# Classname.this.memberName vs memberName

Tags: java, android, member, static-members

What's difference between getting methods `MyFragment.this.mFragment` and `mFragment`? I have a member in parent class

```
private Fragment mFragment;
```

I've tried this check in inner class

`if (mFragment instanceof SecondFragment) {
    if (MyFragment.this.mFragment instanceof SecondFragment) {
       some code...
    }
 }`

The Studio isn't telling any error, that second check is always true. Why?

Comment: When the first case is true then the second case is true as well. :-)

Comment: is there any diff between seeing parent's member ??

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

There may not be a difference in your case. That depends on the context. 
`mFragment instanceof SecondFragment` refers to the instance variable (member) of the current class. I assume you use your code snippet within some method of MyFragment.

`MyFragment.this.mFragment` works there as well, but it does work in inner classes too. Those may be explicit inner classes (another class in the same .class file) as well as anonymous inner classes a listeners etc. There you have to use 
`MyFragment.this.mFragment`

Answer (score 0):

Decompile your .class file and verify it.
You can find a reference available in inner class to access outer class behaviours.